# Install latest php_intl on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: php, symfony, ubuntu-10.04, updates, intl

I'm using the Ondřej Surý source for the latest php Version on Ubuntu 10.04.
So i get PHP Version 5.4.12-1~lucid+1

For my Symfony2 applciation I need the latest version of the php-intl extension.

On my local XAMPP Server I am running

- INTL version 1.1.0
- ICU version  **4.6.1**

On my webserver is only this one:

- INTL version 1.1.0
- ICU version  **4.2.1**

Is there a source or a way to update it too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to compile a more recent version of ICU from source and then recompile the PHP intl extension.

Building ICU from source is pretty standard (configure, make, sudo make install). You can pass `--prefix` to configure to select the installation location.

The easiest way to recompile the PHP intl extension is to remove the one you currently have (`apt-get remove php5-intl`) and install the PECL version (`pecl install intl`). You will be asked for the location of the ICU files.